# Redirect User To Login login if app close not (minimize)

Tags: android, android-intent

I build a Android app which can let user log in, using `SharedPreferences` for storing user session. But if app close (not minimize or press back button), i was stuck in here, **please write with right code**, not example

**SplasScreen Activity**

```
public class SplashscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int SPLASH_TIME = 2000;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //----dark mode----------
        preferences=getSharedPreferences("push",MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences.getBoolean("dark",false)){
            AppCompatDelegate
                    .setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }else {
            AppCompatDelegate
                    .setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(SPLASH_TIME);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(preferences.getBoolean("user", false)) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

this my loginactivty
**Login Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etEmail,etPass;
    private TextView tvSignUp,tvReset;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //---analytics-----------
        FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "id");
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "login_activity");
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "activity");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        etEmail=findViewById(R.id.email);
        etPass=findViewById(R.id.password);
        tvSignUp=findViewById(R.id.signup);
        btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.signin);
        tvReset=findViewById(R.id.reset_pass);

        tvReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,PassResetActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!isValidEmailAddress(etEmail.getText().toString())){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please enter valid email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(etPass.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    String email = "&&email="+etEmail.getText().toString();
                    String pass = "&&password="+etPass.getText().toString();
                    String url = new ApiResources().getLogin()+email+pass;
                    login(url);
                }
            }
        });
        tvSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void login(String url){
        dialog.show();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                dialog.cancel();
                try {

                    if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("name", response.getString("name"));
                        editor.putString("email", etEmail.getText().toString());
                        editor.putString("id",response.getString("user_id"));
                        editor.putBoolean("status",true);
                        editor.apply();

                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }else if (response.getString("status").equals("error")){
                        new ToastMsg(LoginActivity.this).toastIconError(response.getString("data"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.cancel();
                new ToastMsg(LoginActivity.this).toastIconError(getString(R.string.error_toast));
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
        String ePattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
        java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(ePattern);
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
        return m.matches();
    }



}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NavigationAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<NavigationModel> list =new ArrayList<>();
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private String[] navItemImage;

    private String[] navItemName2;
    private String[] navItemImage2;
    private boolean status=false;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //---analytics-----------
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "id");
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "main_activity");
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "activity");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

        //----dark mode----------
        preferences=getSharedPreferences("push",MODE_PRIVATE);
//        if (preferences.getBoolean("dark",false)){
//            AppCompatDelegate
//                    .setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
//        }else {
//            AppCompatDelegate
//                    .setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
//        }




        //----init---------------------------
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        //----navDrawer------------------------
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //----fetch array------------
        String[] navItemName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_name);
        navItemImage=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_image);
        navItemImage2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_image_2);


        navItemName2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_name_2);




        //----navigation view items---------------------
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacingItemDecoration(2, Tools.dpToPx(this, 15), true));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        status = prefs.getBoolean("status",false);

        if (status){
            for (int i = 0; i< navItemName.length; i++){
                NavigationModel models =new NavigationModel(navItemImage[i], navItemName[i]);
                list.add(models);
            }
        }else {
            for (int i=0;i<navItemName2.length;i++){
                NavigationModel models =new NavigationModel(navItemImage2[i],navItemName2[i]);
                list.add(models);
            }
        }







        //set data and list adapter
        mAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        final NavigationAdapter.OriginalViewHolder[] viewHolder = {null};

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NavigationAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, NavigationModel obj, int position, NavigationAdapter.OriginalViewHolder holder) {

                Log.e("POSITION OF NAV:::", String.valueOf(position));

                //----action for click items nav---------------------

                if (position==0){
                    loadFragment(new MainHomeFragment());
                }
                else if (position==1){
                    loadFragment(new MoviesFragment());
                }
                else if (position==2){
                    loadFragment(new LiveTvFragment());
                }
                else if (position==3){
                    loadFragment(new TvSeriesFragment());
                }
                else if (position==4){
                    loadFragment(new GenreFragment());
                }
                else if (position==5){
                    loadFragment(new CountryFragment());
                }
                else {


                    if (status){

                        if (position==6){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if (position==7){
                            loadFragment(new FavoriteFragment());
                        }
                        else if (position==8){
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage("Are you sure to logout ?")
                                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                            editor.putBoolean("status",false);
                                            editor.apply();

                                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    }).create().show();
                        }
                        else if (position==9){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (position==6){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if (position==7){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

                }




                //----behaviour of bg nav items-----------------
                if (!obj.getTitle().equals("Settings") && !obj.getTitle().equals("Login") && !obj.getTitle().equals("Sign Out")){

                    if (preferences.getBoolean("dark",false)){
                        mAdapter.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position,R.color.nav_bg);
                    }else {
                        mAdapter.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position,R.color.white);
                    }


                    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    holder.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    viewHolder[0] =holder;
                }

                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });

        //----external method call--------------
        loadFragment(new MainHomeFragment());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){

        if (fragment!=null){

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                    .commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_search:

                final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("q",s);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }else {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage("Do you want to exit ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).create().show();

        }
    }

    //----nav menu item click---------------
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        // set item as selected to persist highlight
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


        return true;
    }
}
```

i put checking code `if(preferences.getBoolean("user", false)) {` on `splashscreen`, thanks advance

Comment: Do you mean kittling the app by the system itself?

Comment: maybe yes, but if app was open (first time or no) will start Splashscreen > MainActivity > (if not login will redirect to login) after login success will back again to MainActivity, in this case in my app, if you minimize, this save state and not logout from app, but if you clean task this app will force logout and need login again

Answer (score 0):

Just give this in manifeast file when ever app open it will launch login page if you want to store login  details use sharedpref to store data and use it

```
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```